# Scala, pattern matching on a tuple of generic trait, checking if types are equal

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, traits

I know a lot of questions exist about type erasure and pattern matching on generic types, but I could not understand what should I do in my case from answers to those, and I could not explain it better in title.

Following code pieces are simplified to present my case.

So I have a trait

```
 trait Feature[T] {
      value T
      def sub(other: Feature[T]): Double
 }

 // implicits for int,float,double etc to Feature with sub mapped to - function
 ...
```

Then I have a class

```
 class Data(val features: IndexedSeq[Feature[_]]) {
     def sub(other: Data): IndexedSeq[Double] = {
         features.zip(other.features).map {
             case(e1: Feature[t], e2: Feature[y]) => e1 sub e2.asInstanceOf[Feature[t]]
         }
     }    
 }
```

And I have a test case like this

```
case class TestFeature(val value: String) extends Feature[String] {
     def sub(other: Feature[String]): Double = value.length - other.length
}

val testData1 = new Data(IndexedSeq(8, 8.3f, 8.232d, TestFeature("abcd"))
val testData2 = new Data(IndexedSeq(10, 10.1f, 10.123d, TestFeature("efg"))

testData1.sub(testData2).zipWithIndex.foreach { 
  case (res, 0) => res should be (8 - 10)
  case (res, 1) => res should be (8.3f - 10.1f)
  case (res, 2) => res should be (8.232d - 10.123d)
  case (res, 3) => res should be (1)
}
```

This somehow works. If I try sub operation with instances of `Data` that have different types in same index of `features`, I get a `ClassCastException`. This actually satisfies my requirements, but if possible I would like to use `Option` instead of throwing an exception. How can I make following code work?

```
 class Data(val features: IndexedSeq[Feature[_]]) {
     def sub(other: Data): IndexedSeq[Double] = {
         features.zip(other.features).map {
             // of course this does not work, just to give idea
             case(e1: Feature[t], e2: Feature[y]) if t == y => e1 sub e2.asInstanceOf[Feature[t]]
         }
     }    
 }
```

Also I am really inexperienced in Scala, so I would like to get feedback on this type of structure. Are there another ways to do this and which way would make most sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics don't exist at runtime, and an `IndexedSeq[Feature[_]]` has forgotten what the type parameter is even at compile time (@Jatin's answer won't allow you to construct a `Data` with a list of mixed types of `Feature[_]`). The easiest answer might be just to catch the exception (using `catching` and `opt` from `scala.util.control.Exception`). But, to answer the question as written:

You could check the classes at runtime:

```
case (e1: Feature[t], e2: Feature[y]) if e1.value.getClass ==
  e2.value.getClass => ...
```

Or include the type information in the `Feature`:

```
trait Feature[T] {
  val value: T
  val valueType: ClassTag[T] // write classOf[T] in subclasses
  def maybeSub(other: Feature[_]) = other.value match {
    case valueType(v) => Some(actual subtraction)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

The more complex "proper" solution is probably to use Shapeless `HList` to preserve the type information in your lists:

```
// note the type includes the type of all the elements
val l1: Feature[Int] :: Feature[String] :: HNil = f1 :: f2 :: HNil
val l2 = ...

// a 2-argument function that's defined for particular types
// this can be applied to `Feature[T], Feature[T]` for any `T`
object subtract extends Poly2 {
  implicit def caseFeatureT[T] =
    at[Feature[T], Feature[T]]{_ sub _}
}
// apply our function to the given HLists, getting a HList
// you would probably inline this
// could follow up with .toList[Double]
// since the resulting HList is going to be only Doubles
def subAll[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList](l1: L1, l2: L2)(
  implicit zw: ZipWith[L1, L2, subtract.type]) =
  l1.zipWith(l2)(subtract)
```

That way `subAll` can only be called for `l1` and `l2` all of whose elements match, *and this is enforced at compile time*. (If you really want to do `Option`s you can have two `at`s in the `subtract`, one for same-typed `Feature[T]`s and one for different-typed `Feature[_]`s, but ruling it out entirely seems like a better solution)

Comment: Comparing `e1.value.getClass` and `e2.value.getClass` solves my problem in short term. `HList` s in Shapeless are definitely interesting, I will try to upgrade to that in time as compile time enforcement sounds so good to me, but I need to learn more about type system of Scala to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
class Data[T: TypeTag](val features: IndexedSeq[Feature[T]]) {

    val t = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]

    def sub[E: TypeTag](other: Data[E]): IndexedSeq[Double] = {
        val e = implicitly[TypeTag[E]]
        features.zip(other.features).flatMap{
            case(e1, e2: Feature[y]) if e.tpe == t.tpe  => Some(e1 sub e2.asInstanceOf[Feature[T]])
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
case class IntFeature(val value: Int) extends Feature[Int] {
    def sub(other: Feature[Int]): Double = value - other.value
}
 val testData3 = new Data(IndexedSeq(TestFeature("abcd")))
 val testData4 = new Data(IndexedSeq(IntFeature(1)))
 println(testData3.sub(testData4).zipWithIndex)
```

gives `Vector()`

Comment: I marked @lmm s answer as correct, and as he said, this won't allow me to include different types in same instance of Data.